# What does "java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature" mean?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, oracle11g

My question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673626/jdbc-callablestatement-and-oracle-sys-refcursor-in-parameters?rq=1) and [a post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051271/calling-pl-sql-procedure-with-sys-refcursor-as-in-parameter-using-jdbc) . I am trying to pass REF_CURSOR as an IN parameter while calling a PL/SQL procedure using JDBC. Here is my code:

```
 public int printMaxSalAllDept()
 {
     Connection conn = null;
     OracleCallableStatement callStmt = null;
     int rowCount = -1;

     try 
     {
         // Register the Jdbc Driver
         // Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_ORACLE);

         // Create a Database connection
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PWD);

         // Create a query string to get the ResultSet of your choice
         String getRsQuery = "SELECT e.department_id , e.last_name , "
                             + "e.salary FROM employees e , (SELECT department_id , "
                             + "MAX(salary) AS maxSal FROM employees GROUP BY department_id) "
                             + "m WHERE e.department_id = m.department_id "
                             + "AND e.salary = m.maxSal ORDER BY e.salary";

         // Create a Statement
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

         // Execute the statement
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getRsQuery);


         // Create a SQL String
         String callProc = "{ call HR.EMP_PKG.print_max_sal_all_dept(? , ?) }";

         // Create a Callable Statement
         callStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(callProc);

         // Bind values to the IN parameter
         callStmt.setCursor(1, rs);
         // callStmt.setNull(1,OracleTypes.CURSOR);

         // Register OUT parameters type to the SQL type of the value returned
         callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

         // Execute Callable Statements
         callStmt.execute();

         // Retrieve value from the OUT parameters
         rowCount = callStmt.getInt(0);
         System.out.println("Number of rows in the cursor :" + rowCount);
     } 
     catch (SQLException se) 
     {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in the database");
        System.out.println("Exception message: "+ se.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Database error code: "+ se.getErrorCode());
        se.printStackTrace();
     }
     finally
     {
        // Clean up
        if(callStmt != null)
        {
            try
            {
                callStmt.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(conn != null)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException se2) 
            {
                se2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
     return rowCount;
 }
```

When I run the above code I get the following exception:

```
Exception occured in the database
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setCursorInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5867)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setCursor(OracleCallableStatement.java:5297)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setCursor(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:410)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.printMaxSalAllDept(HrManager.java:1038)
    at com.rolta.HrManager.main(HrManager.java:1344)
Exception message: Unsupported feature
Database error code: 17023
```

I have seen couple of posts in this forum and others which suggests updating to the latest version of JDBC driver fixes this issue. In my case I am using the latest version of JDBC driver for Oracle (    `ojdbc6.jar` the very first jar under [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 11.2.0.4 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html)) . So i don't think its the version that's causing the issue.

If what I was doing was illegal the exception message thrown would have indicated that. **But here with "Unsupported Feature" message it seems like this feature is either unavailable for my database(or its version that I am using (11g) ) or for the version of the JDBC driver that I am using. Is this the right interpretation of this exception ?**

Comment: Did you look up what the error code `17023` corresponds to in your database documentation?

Comment: which version of jdbc jar you are adding in classpath

Comment: Have updated my post to reflect the version of jdbc jar I am using.

Comment: What part of "Unsupported feature" is unclear? Also 11.2.0.4 is not the latest driver, the latest is 12.1.0.2. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But i am using oracle 11g and Java 1,6. Which is why I picked the jar mentioned in the post.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The part of the post in bold is my understanding of the exception. Is that correct ? Will the feature be supported in another version of the Oracle database / Jdbc driver or is this feature not available/supported at all ?

Comment: The 12c driver should also work with 11g, and it is newer and therefor more likely to have new features and improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the feature is not supported in any version of the JDBC driver, and will never be supported.  The version of the database in this situation is not relevant.

I can't say why there ever was a `setCursor()` method declared in `OraclePreparedStatement`.  I would guess that it was a mistake in the design of the API.  In fact, you get a deprecation warning if you compile any code that attempts to call `setCursor()`:

```
C:\>javac -Xlint JavaRefCursorTest.java
JavaRefCursorTest.java:28: warning: [deprecation] setCursor(int,ResultSet) in OraclePreparedStatement has been deprecated
                    ((OracleCallableStatement)cstmt2).setCursor(1, rSet);
                                                     ^
1 warning
```

This deprecation warning suggests that Oracle are planning to remove this method in the future.

I've also run my `JavaRefCursorTest` class from [my answer to one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27083378/) with the Oracle 12c JDBC driver (ojdbc7.jar).  The end result is only slightly different: the type of exception thrown when calling `setCursor()` is `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` instead of `java.sql.SQLException`.  So upgrading the JDBC driver JAR won't help.

In your case, I can't see the reason why you would want to get a ref cursor out of the database and into a JDBC `ResultSet`, only to pass the same `ResultSet` straight back to the database.  You can call the procedure with a ref cursor directly, using a PL/SQL block such as the one below:

```
String plsql = 
    "DECLARE" +
    "  l_curs   SYS_REFCURSOR; " +
    "BEGIN" +
    "  OPEN l_curs FOR" +
    "     SELECT e.department_id , e.last_name ," +
    "            e.salary FROM employees e , (SELECT department_id ," +
    "            MAX(salary) AS maxSal FROM employees GROUP BY department_id)" +
    "            m WHERE e.department_id = m.department_id" + 
    "            AND e.salary = m.maxSal ORDER BY e.salary;" +
    "" +            
    "  HR.EMP_PKG.print_max_sal_all_dept(l_curs, ?);" +
    "END;"

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(plsql);
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: So, basically its an illegal  request/operation in Jdbc. I think the current exception message is just misleading.